# Why autovivification works at 'for'?

Tags: perl, autovivification

I have next code:

```
print   for @{ $events->{ $name } };
```

When `$events` is empty hash I got `$name` key which value is empty array `[]`

Why autovivification works despite on that I just access element and assign nothing to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206836/why-does-perl-autovivify-in-this-case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41400902/4632019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning doesn't autovivify; evaluating as an lvalue so that you can assign does.

Foreach's list expression is evaluated as an lvalue to allow `$_ = 1 for @a;`