# Promotion of undef variable to ARRAY ref in foreach

Tags: perl

```
use strict;                  
use warnings FATAL => 'all'; 

my $x = undef;               
if (@$x) { print "ok\n" }    
else { print "no\n" }
```

Predictably yields *"Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference"* for `if (@$x)`.  But inserting a `foreach (@$x)`:

```
use strict;                  
use warnings FATAL => 'all'; 

my $x = undef;               
foreach (@$x) { print $_ }  # <------- 
if (@$x) { print "ok\n" }    
else { print "no\n" }        

print ref($x)."\n";
```

Outputs:

```
no
ARRAY
```

The `foreach` line seems to have made an assignment to `$x`.  What's up with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Perl autovivify in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206836/why-does-perl-autovivify-in-this-case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autovivification makes

```
@$x
```

equivalent to

```
@{ $x //= [] }
```

in lvalue context.

Use

```
if ($x) {
   for (@$x) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: The question (as I understand it) was why is `for` an lvalue context.

Comment: @choroba, I don't think so (because it's a warning in rvalue context, and there's no mention of rvalue context. But just in case, the following is the answer to that: Because the loop body could assign to the loop iterator and change the values. (e.g. `for (@a) { $_ = uc($_); }`)

Comment: I know, just trying to help make the answer more informative :-)